# Order of evaluation in C

Tags: c, operator-precedence

The code below gives an answer (further below), that I do not understand.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fA (int x) {
   int w = x;

   printf("%d", x);

   if (x > 4) 
      w += fA(x - 2);

   if (x > 2)
      w += fA(x - 4);

   printf("%d", x);
   return w;
}

int fB (int x) {

   if (x < 1) 
      return 1;

   int w = x;

   if (x > 2) 
      w = w * fB(x - 1);

   if (x > 1) 
      w= w + fA(x - 1);

   return w;
}

int main (void) {
   printf("\n %d %d \n", fA(6), fB(3));
   return 0;
}
```

it prints

> 112264004226
>  12 11

The question is why?
In my opinion it should starts with `6`.
Thanks!

Comment: Learn [ask]. Questions have to be self-contained and not just rely on external links!

Answer (score 5):

There is no guarantee that parameters to a function will be evaluated in any particular order.

So when you call `printf` with `fA(6)` and `fB(3)` as parameters, the compiler is free to call either one before the other.

In this particular case, `fB(3)` was evaluated first.  But if you use a different compiler, it might evaluate `fA(6)` first.

Answer (score 3):

There's no defined order. This depends on compiler, for example on:

```
# gcc -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-    dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0
Thread model: posix
```

this produces

> 640042261122
>  12 11

Moreover - the same compiler may decide order to be different for optimization

Answer (score 1):

Is this a puzzle?

I imagine you expect it to start with a 6 because fA(6) comes first.  But printf's arguments are being evaluated in reverse order (by my compiler; YMMV), so fB(3) is called first.

Comment: A more general observation is that there is no guarantee of the order of evaluation of expressions in any statement; there is only a guarantee of the order that the operators are applied. So with a statement like `f(x) + g(y) * h(z)` the three functions may be executed in any order; the only guarantee is that the _result_ of evaluating g(y) will be multiplied by the _result_ of evaluating h(z) before that result will be added to the _result_ of evaluating f(x)

Comment: Yeah, you right.  I updated my response accordingly.